# Maximum of Each Row and return the columname in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

having a data frame as below:

[image: data]

I need to find the largest value in each row and return the column name.

Expected output:

[image: output]

I tried the below code:

```
df['Max'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
error:TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding `numeric_only` flag would solve your problem:

```
# Panda 1.5.2
import pandas as pd

d = {'prod': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3'], 'p1': [10, 20.0, 30], 'p2': [7 ,6 ,4], 'p3': [12,50,5], 'MAX': ['','','']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(type(df)) # <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
df['MAX'] = df.idxmax(1, numeric_only=True)
print(df)
```

Check your pandas version. `numeric_only` was added to `idxmax` in pandas 1.5.0.

```
pip show pandas
```

Check type of your data as @Niko suggests

Comment: df['Max']=df.idxmax(axis=1,numeric_only=True), I tried the code.

Comment: error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [361], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df['Max']=df.idxmax(axis=1,numeric_only=True)

TypeError: idxmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'numeric_only'

Comment: The type of your data frame or one of the columns is wrong. print(df['columnName'].dtype use this to check what type is for every column, if one column returns object instead of numeric use df[column name] = pd.to_numeric(df[column name]) to convert

Comment: type of the dataframe is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: One of the column is object.